# How to compress PDF when creating from GIF files?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdf-generation, gif, macos-mojave

I have ~200 gif black-and-white files, 600-900 Kb each. The overall size is about 102 Mb.
I create pdf from them -

```
convert *.gif result.pdf
```

`result.pdf` file size is about 98 Mb. But I need a PDF file of size less than 25 Mb.
I tried different options - compress, quality, density - but none of them helped.

What else could I try?

Comment: I do not know if you can compress a PDF. But you can "compress" the input GIFs by reducing the number of colors contained in them using +dither -colors N. Or creating a color map image and using -remap. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#colors

Comment: @fmw42, images are B&W.. upd. hm, but stored as RGB

Comment: Perhaps convert the GIFS to FAX or GROUP4 compressed TIFF. Try `convert *.gif -compress FAX -type bilevel -format tiff:- | convert - result.pdf`

Comment: @fmw42, `convert: missing an image filename `tiff:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3223.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/566.
convert: no images defined `result.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3226`

Comment: My command works fine for me. What did you type? Did you include the pipe `|` symbol and make my command as one command, not two? What do you get from `convert -version`? Post one of your typical GIF images

Comment: @fmw42, ImageMagick 6.9.11-30 Q16 x86_64 2020-09-19. I copied everything. Here is the sample file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnqlvkjkznn3euk/150_orig.gif?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left in -format. The command should be: `convert 150_orig.gif -compress FAX -type bilevel tiff:- | convert - result.pdf`  This reduces the file size from 613448B to 157477B.

Comment: @fmw42, many thanks. Please post it as an answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
convert 150_orig.gif -compress FAX -type bilevel tiff:- | convert - result.pdf
```

This reduces the file size from 613448B to 157477B.